# Admin permissions are required to set 'limit to' or 'also add' participant role for scheduled reminders?

Tags: civievent, scheduled-reminders

We have noticed that if you don't have CiviCRM:Administer CiviCRM permissions, in scheduled reminders for an event if 'limit  to' (or 'also include') is set to 'participant role', the drop-down box for *which* participant role does not appear. So they can select 'limit to' (or 'also include') and 'participant role', but not then select a role.

We would like non-adminstrator level permissions (with all relevant event-level permissions) to be able to select which participant roles an event scheduled reminder is limited to (or adds on).

This feels like a bug to me? Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two explanations come to mind:

1. Scheduled reminders are often set up by administrators so in many
   cases the current arrangement is fine.
2. CiviCRM:Administer CiviCRM is a
   default requirement so it is possible no-one has worked through what
   permissions make sense if it is not an administrator configuring the
   reminders.

I'd suggest you create an issue at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues and describe how you think the permissions should work in that area.

However, unless you can contribute code or sponsor someone to do the change, it is unlikely to be implemented quickly - but you might get lucky: sometimes people getting started with Civi development are looking for small changes to work on.

Comment: OK- thanks for the response and info! Since those without admin permissions can do everything except see the drop-down role box for recipients, it feels more like a bug than a change. I'll submit.

Comment: Submitted: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1568 Thanks!